# Laravel 5.5 with ajax showing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, csrf

I sent an Ajax call which showed an error message:

> 500 Internal Server Error

I have gone through some posts over Stackoverflow and understand that I have to passed csrf token. Thus, I have pasted this following code within the head section (just before the closing of the head tag).

```
<meta name="csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Also, here is the Ajax codes that I called;

```
$.ajax({
                        headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content')
                        },
                        url: "adminUser/exportselected/1",
                        type:'POST',
                        data: {selected:selected, selectedField:selectedField},
                        success: function(data) { 
                            window.location = data.path;
                            if($.isEmptyObject(data.error)){
                                //alert(data);
                            }else{
                                //alert(data.error);
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

As you can see from the above, I have also passed the token with the headers. Anything else I need to do?

My route (web.php) is as under:

```
Route::post('adminUser/exportselected/{page?}', 'Administrator\AdminUserController@exportSelected');
```

Below is my controller code;

public function exportSelected($page, Request $request) {

```
if (\Request::isMethod('post')) {
        $adminUserDataExcelSelected = UserAdmin::getAdminUserListExcelSelected($request->selectedField, $request->selected)->get();
        $excelName = "Admin-Users".Carbon::now();
        $path = public_path('export/'.$excelName);

        ob_end_clean();
        ob_start();
        Excel::create($excelName, function($excel) use($adminUserDataExcelSelected) {
        $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet) use($adminUserDataExcelSelected) {
        $sheet->fromArray($adminUserDataExcelSelected);
        });
        })->store('xlsx', public_path('exports'));
        ob_flush();
        //dd(url('/'));
        $creatingPath = url('/')."/exports/".$excelName.".xlsx";
        //return response()->download(public_path('a.xlsx'));
        return response()->json(['path' => $creatingPath]);
        //return response()->download($path);
    }

}
```

Comment: Add dataType: 'json'; to ajax above your data

Comment: @mafortis kindly put the same as answer with more explanation / code

Comment: See the log file (storage/logs/larave.log) for an answer. Laravel writes error details there.

Answer (score 0):

You should add dataType to your ajax and also move headers out of your ajax code below function, here is sample code

```
..... .on(click, function (){
headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content') },

$.ajax({ 

url: "adminUser/exportselected/1",
 type:'POST', data: {selected:selected,
 selectedField:selectedField},

dataType : "json",

 success: function(data) { window.location = data.path; if($.isEmptyObject(data.error)){ //alert(data); }else{ //alert(data.error); } } });
```

Ps: I'm with phone my code might be a bit messy, sorry for that.

Comment: I have added the same but nothing changed. I have also updated the question with controller method. Can you please check?

Answer (score 0):

actually you should check the browser console for what's happen in the server. the laravel `csrfTokenMissMatch` throw `Laravel 419 post error` not the `500 code`. so check your controller `exportSelected()` method for what's is wrong that.
you are verified the csrf successfully . the 500 error is come from the controller method, not from laravel csrf middleware.

Comment: I have updated my question with the controller code. Its a simple method. Can you please look into it?